# JS minifying/unit tester/builder

Tags: windows, javascript, unit-tests, lint

Looking for a Windows (or cross-platform) JS builder that

- minifies,
- runs unit tests
- runs jshint/jslint
- can compare to a coding style guide
- can download external sources
- can combine multiple JS files into one combine minified file and adjust references to point to the minified file.

GUI or CLI fine. I presume most of those functions would need to be given hints in some make file like input. Open source preferred but certainly not required.

Comment: The [Maven Javascript Extensions](http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/) can do all of this, but sadly haven't been maintained in a while, and can be a bit of a steep learning curve.

Comment: grunt is often used for these tasks. I don't know a good package that does all out-of-the-box, though.

Comment: grunt looks great - feel free to do that as an answer. I really don't mind having to configure; yes that is harder for some but I figure if I can write a html/php/ajax/jQuery application I should be able to configure a tool to save me work.

Comment: As of voting this as "primarily opinion-based" - that's the feature of recommendations. Almost always recommendations are opinion-based. With requirements listed on this question, it's easy to recommend a good tool for the task.

Comment: Since no one has done an answer I guess I'll just have to right one up so that it can be not dragging down our answered perecentage...

Comment: Anyone tried Microsoft's rush and rushstack? Seems like it could be relevant, and it's out in the open for some months already.

Comment: Have you considered replacing the old jshint with babel+prettier? Or just babel (with tweaked rules it can do 90% of what prettier does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) is a highly configurable build system. It runs via [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and has a [multitude of plugins](http://gruntjs.com/plugins) available to do a lot of specific tasks. Individual tasks are highly configurable and writing new tasks is also quite easy.

To go over the requirements:

- *minifies:* Yes for JavaScript via the official [uglify](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify), for images via the official [imagemin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-imagemin), for CSS via the official [CSSMin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-imagemin) and for HTML also has an official [minifier plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-htmlmin).
- *runs unit tests:* Yes multiple different unit testing frameworks have grunt plugins - two popular and officially supported ones are [NodeUnit](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) and [QUnit](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit)
- *runs jshint/jslint:* Yes - there is an official [jshint integration plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-jshint).
- *can compare to a coding style guide:* Yes - via the [jscs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jscs-checker) it is very easy and that plugin also includes a whole ton of presets so is really great.
- *can download external sources:* If set up right it can though I haven't ended up needing this.
- *can combine multiple JS files into one combine minified file and adjust the html's links to reference only that file:* the [Concat official plugin will do this if set up right](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-concat) or see also the [UseMin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-usemin) plugin.